# How can the sapper static file base URL be specified?

Tags: svelte

I would like the files that live in static/ to be served at e.g. `static/` instead of at `/`.

I tried just changing the polka "base" in the call to "`use(sirv`"... but it seems the sapper middleware interferes and makes it 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try just putting everything in a `project_root/static/static` directory instead. That *should* work, though it might feel a little awkward.

Sapper expects that the `static` folder will be served as is, and bases things like the service worker manifest on the contents of this folder. This is probably a bit brittle and should be configurable — if you have suggestions for how this area could be improved, feel free to raise an issue on https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper.